# How do I handle async tests in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to write a test to make sure that an entity cannot be added to google cloud datastore twice according to some validation (or unique key made up by multiple fields).

To give you an example, let's say I want to save a simple `image_url` and a `type`. Now there can only be one image that has a certain URL and a certain type.

This is easy enough to check (at least for now I verify that my datastore does not find an entity with such values).

But when writing a test, I get inconsistent results due to latency I suppose. So something like:

```
def test_foo_bar(self):
    self.datastore.save_image(self.image_metadata)
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
        self.datastore.save_image(self.image_metadata)
```

Now the problem seems to be that by the time I check if an entity already exists, the just created entity is not there yet (?). So it doesn't throw an error, creates a duplicate and the test fails. This far the only way to get some consistency was to add a `time.sleep(1)` to give it more time, but still, at times the test doesn't pass (although it does most of the time). I personally don't like this inconsistency.

What is a good approach to avoid this behavior?

Comment: The most important quesion is: what is guaranteed here? You seem to say that there is no guarantee that the image is saved after `.save_image` call returns. So what else can you do? If there is no guarantee, there is nothing you can do. If there is a guarantee, for example "image will be saved after 10s" then you should try after 10s. Also asynchronity is one thing, incosistency the other. Why does `.save_image` method create duplicate? This shouldn't happen, no matter when the actual saving happens.

Comment: I see, there's no safe guarantee but one can only hope that it will never take more than, for example, 5s. Other than that I can only completely mock the datastore so that it all happens locally without any actual connection to it and leave that for e2e testing. Would that be a good idea ?

Comment: In regards to duplicates, the only way to prevent duplicate creation is by checking if an entity with that data has been created before. In order for me to test that I have to try and create the same resource twice and get an error. So I'm not sure what you mean there, it can only happen AFTER a resource has been saved already. Maybe I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: (1) Sure, you can do e2e testing, but you will have the same problem there. You don't solve anything. (2) You talk about "duplicates". If I try to add the same row twice (with the same id) I will get an error (assuming id is unique). No duplicate can happen. And saving being synchronous or not doesn't matter. So what I don't understand: how can you get duplicates in this scenario? One of the saves should fail eventually. Unless its a limitation of google cloud datastore?

Comment: Oh ok, so datastore is quite flexible. When I create a resource I just specify values for each column (as you would expect) and the id is autogenerated for you so there's never conflicts on ids (as any DB system would do). So I can create 1000 entries with same url and type and they will all have different ids. One thing I can do is to generate an id based on the unique fields (maybe a hash of url and type) so that duplicates will have conflicting ids and datastore will not allow it to begin with. Datastore does not guarantee uniqueness unless you manually specify an id, which I think I'll do.

Comment: You're depending on an external service (google cloud), and it may not have guarantees of immediate consistency. You *could* mock out the dependency and instead assert that the function is *called* correctly. This is a "weaker" test in terms of making sure your functionality is correct, but it will be consistent and never fail (unless something goes horribly wrong)

Comment: I will give that a try and see if the test will be more consistent, otherwise I'll go the mocking route as also mentioned by @MattMessersmith

Comment: Also, is it really a problem if a duplicate gets created and smashes over the old old? At the end of the day you'll get the same result in the datastore: albeit in a slightly different way. I don't think this particular test is really buying you much...

Comment: @G4bri3l generating ids is certainly one option. And not a bad one. I don't know much about google datastores obviously, but the other option is to consider using some other service with strong consistency model. That would be the option for me.

Comment: Thank you all guys for the suggestions! For now I am stuck with datastore and will move to something else later on thankfully. It's true that duplicates won't matter that much but at this stage I am also using this opportunity to get more comfortable with testing in python. So yeah I am also writing non essential tests.